# how to create an instance of class with two different variable parameters in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

This code has two classes, it looks like the class `Player()` have the same code as `Block()`, I want to minimalize the code, so I don't repeat the spell-like that, and the way to do that is the instances the class, **the `Player()` is an instance of the `Block()`**, how?

```
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):

        super().__init__()
        
        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 15])
        self.image.fill(BLUE)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0

    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        self.change_x += x
        self.change_y += y
    
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        self.rect.y += self.change_y
```

After looking for an answer from you guys, the code just like this:

```
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Player(Block):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height, x, y):
        
        Block.__init__(self, color, width, height)

        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0

    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        self.change_x += x
        self.change_y += y
    
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        self.rect.y += self.change_y
```

Is that code true? When I'm running the program, it works.

Comment: Unless Player inherits from Block, Player instances are not instances of Block.

Comment: hmm thanks, about that riddle :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like Player and Block **inherit** from `pygame.sprite.Sprite`, you can have Player instead **inherit** from Block:

```
class Player(Block):
```

Then, call `super().__init__()` to use Block's constructor (which in turn will also call `pygame.sprite.Sprite`'s constructor):

```
class Player(Block):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
```

Then under that, add all the code specific to Player.

Comment: Im just thinking, when i change the parameters from Player(x, y) to Player(color, width, height, x, y) and then in code `class Player(Block):` after that im added `Block.__init__(self, color, width, height)` and it is works, is that call instance right ?

Answer (score -1):

add a middle Class:

```
class Middle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    super().__init__()

    self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 15])
    self.image.fill(BLUE)

    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

then class Block and class Player inherit from the Middle class